# Show only thumbnail of video on jsp page

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I am trying to show only thumbnail of a video on jsp page without downloading video. Can anyone tell me is this possible or not? Or if possible what is solution for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video Refer this like this may help you

Comment: Thanks It's worked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, If you already have posters of videos and you just want to show it in you jsp page then you should follow the link mentioned in comment by '@user3151627'. But if you want to create a thumbnail image directly from URL then you can use library like FFmpeg etc. For this please have a look on the below link:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

Hope you find it helpful..Thanks!!

Comment: No need to say thanks buddy..I hope I point you to right direction :)