# display multiple videos in one page using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, video

I try to read multiple videos, but I encountered a problem when loading them, **the problem is that the browser crash and the loading time of all videos is very long**, I dont know if it is possible to display only the title and an image of every video,,, After that when the user wants to watch a specific video, in this case he load this video and watch it in streaming mode, but not loading them all at the same time (is there any soft/smart solution for that)

> this is the Controller methode :

```
public function videos()
{
$videos = Video::all();
return view("videos", compact('videos'));
}
```

> this is the view blade :

```
<div class="row">
@foreach ($videos as $v)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">
            <video class="video" controls>
                <source src="{{URL::asset("/videos/upload/$v->file_name")}}" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
        <div class="card-title">
             {{ $v->title }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: set `autostart="false"` to `source`

Comment: I tried this, Bur even with autostart = false Or autopaly = false the browser does not support the size of the videos to display and it crashes

Comment: try `<video class="video" poster="placeholder.png" controls>`

Comment: here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video

Comment: how many videos are you loading? what do you mean by the browser crashes? have you optimized the videos for streaming (MOOV atom at the start)? You could write code that displays the title and maybe a poster image, and only loads the source of the video after an onclick

Comment: thanks mr Gulshan i tried poster and it works now better than before, But i think i still need a faster solution because it still take some seconds to load the videos, and when i will deploy the app to production i think that there would be some problems...
we can say that it is a Lite version hhh,,THANKS

Comment: Offbeatmammal , i actualy upload multiple videos by theme ( by event  // by topic ), and I propose to users to watch them in frontend...............thanks !!