# How To show video thumbnail on mobile when using video tag html5

Tags: html, mobile, html5-video

I need to see a thumbnail of my video on mobile. So far everything I found didn't work. This is the code i have now:

```
<video class="some_class" controls>
    <source src="some/url/path.mp4" alt="some alt text" >
</video>
```

The things I tried is to add the `preload="metadata"` and my frame to my video source `#t=0.5` but those things didn't work.

It is not possible to use poster because I can't know witch picture the customer wants to use on a specific video.

The problem is very mobile specific due to the fact that the thumbnails works on all the other browsers, except the mobile ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the thumbnail image on HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video)

Comment: My issue is mobile specific. It works on all the browsers except the mobile ones. Also all the solutions there don't work in my situation

Comment: Why is your customer setting those thumbnail images on your videos?

Comment: Well the customer can choose the video due to the fact that we are working with AEM (kind of CMS). That is the reason we can't use a fixed image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add videos in following format as well.

- webm(vp8/vorbis)
- mp4(h264/aac)

It seems Chrome mobile prefers webm if it can get it.

Safari (and probably iOS) will not play a video unless served by a server supporting byte-ranges. Apache, nginx and Amazon S3 for example do support them, but many smaller web servers (like WSGI servers) do not.

If browser able to detect the video then, thumbnail should show.

You can try this plugin [Fancy app](https://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) too.

This plugin will overcome the browser/device compatibility issues.