# <Video> frame thumbnail photo

Tags: html, css, pcloud

My site http://www.kreativekouples.com/videography/
Has a load of videos that are hosted on pCloud but when showcasing on my website it looks odd as they are all black previews. Can I upload a thumnail photo like YouTube allows on their videos?

```
<video width="100%" controls>
  <source src="https://filedn.com/lhwRBSoh6FuH95L1pyyOOz4/kir_manni_wedd.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  <source src="https://filedn.com/lhwRBSoh6FuH95L1pyyOOz4/kir_manni_wedd.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the thumbnail image on HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video)

Comment: Yeah, just add the attribute `poster="/path/to/your/image.jpg"` in the `<video>` element

Comment: Not a duplicate but same request. thanks for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add poster="{photo-url example (placeholder.png)}" to the video tag.

```
<video width="100%" poster="placeholder.png" controls>
```

Your browser does not support HTML5 video.