# How to remove and add the play button in an embedded video of HTML page?

Tags: html

I want to hide the play button from bottom of the video and add it to the center of the video? How can I do this? I am using the approved answer from this discussion thread. [How to set the thumbnail image on HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video)
Thanks.

Here is my code -

```html
<video width="100%" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: The UI for the video element is subject to its implementation in the browser. It's not standard and there are limited ways in which you can style it.  If you want to customize it, you have to remove the controls attribute and build a whole UI from scratch. It's a lot of work, but there are existing libraries that do this

Comment: Thanks, can you please point me to some of the libraries?

Comment: https://plyr.io/ or https://videojs.com/

Comment: thankyou very much